# How to implement if statements in async called celery tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, celery

I am new to async task with flask (celery). My goal is to implement an async task queue .

I have a Flask restful api calling the task. The resource.py looks like this:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from app.tasks import get_data


class Data(Resource):

    def get(self, isin):

        output = get_data.apply_async(args=[isin])

        output_done = output.get()

        return output_done
```

which calls the task in task.py:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@app.task(name='get_data')
def get_data(isin):

    df = pd.read_sql_table("data", engine)

    if isin in df["data"].tolist():
        subset = df[df["data"] == isin].iloc[0]

        output = some_calculation

        return output

    return {'message': 'data not found'}, 404
```

When I run this, the if statement is always executed due to the apply_async.So my question is how to proper implement an if clause in an async task?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong,

- you have a celery task named `get_data`
- you have an api defined in the class `Data`
- when you hit this api, you need to submit the task and it needs to run asynchronously

Now within the task,

- you have `if isin in df["data"].tolist():`
- your problem is, this is running always irrespective of whatever value you give to `isin`

Looking at the code, I don't think its an issue with the code.
It looks like more of a problem with the data.

Could you please share the values of `isin` and `df["data"].tolist()` using which you have tested the code.